# BUSCAR UNA LETRA EN UNA CADENA DE CARACTERES

Tags: c++, c

A partir del contenido del tablero se desea buscar la presencia (ocurrencia) de un determinado caracter.

Por ejemplo el caracter 'a', aparece en el tablero, en la celda del renglón 0 y columa 1, así como en la celda del renglón 0 y columna 2, y también en la celda del renglón 2 y columna 2.
SALIDA: En el primer renglón se deben imprimir la celda en donde aparace el caracter, iniciando con el número de renglón, el caracter coma ',' y el número de columna, después el caracter ':', NOTA: Se deben imprimir todas las ocurrencias del caracter, dando prioridad a la ocurrencia que inicia en una celda con el valor menor para el renglón y como segundo criterio el valor menor de la columna.
Si el caracter no se encuentra se imprime "N/A".

¿con que funcion puedo comparer la letra ingresada por el usuario'?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define REN 10
#define COL 10
/*
EJEMPLO:
EL USUARIO INGRESA LA LETRA A BUSCAR =  a
TAMAÑO DE LA MATRIZ QUE ELIGIO EL USUARIO = 3
MATRIZ DE CARACTERES
a c a
d c c
k l a
*/
 
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
 
    //VARIABLES
    int renglon, columna;
    char caracter, aux;
    int tam;
    char matriz[REN][COL];
 
    //SE LEE DESDE TECLADO LA LETRA A BUSCAR , EL TAMAÑO DE LA MATRIZ
    scanf ("%c",&caracter);
    scanf ("%d",&tam);
    scanf ("%c",&aux); //lee el salto de linea (el cual tiene un codigo 10)
    //CICLO PARA LA CAPTURA DE DATOS
    for(renglon=0; renglon<tam; renglon++){
        for (columna=0; columna<tam; columna++){
            scanf ("%c", &matriz[renglon][columna]);
            scanf ("%c", &aux);
        }
    }
    //Busqueda del aracter en la matriz
    //comenzamos a recorrer la matriz
    //para eso necesitamos compara cada letra de la matriz con la letra que ingreso el usuario
    //por lo que tenemos que recorrer cada una de las seldad de la matriz
    //iniciando en renglon=0, columna =0; hasta
    for(renglon=0; renglon<tam; renglon++){
        for (columna=0; columna<tam; columna++){
            matriz[renglon][columna] == caracter;
            //implementamos la comparación, si se da la igualded se imprime el valor de las coordenadas
 
 
 
        }
    }
 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ¿C o C++? Una respuesta en C++ no tiene por qué ser válida en C y viceversa. Etiqueta las preguntas correctamente, por favor

Comment: Sin mayúsculas sostenidas, por favor, que pareciera que gritas y se considera inapropiado. Edita tu pregunta y ajustas el título; de paso dejas sólo la etiqueta que corresponda a tu pregunta. (usa el enlace Editar bajo la pregunta y las etiquetas)

Answer (score 0):

Con la función `strcmp(variable1,variable2)` de la librería `<string.h>` se pueden comparar, devolverá 0 si son iguales, mayor que 0 si la variable1 es mas grande y menor que 0 si la variable1 es menor.

Answer (score -1):

prueba este codigo.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

const int filas = 1000;
const int columnas = 1000;

void buscarElemento(char matriz[filas][columnas], int dimension, char elemento){
    bool encontro = false;
    for(int i=0;i<dimension;i++){
        for(int j=0; j<dimension; j++){
            if(matriz[i][j] == elemento){
                encontro = true;
                cout<<endl<<i<<","<<j<<": ";
            }
        }
    }

    if(encontro == false){
        cout<<"N/A\n"<<endl;
    }
}

int main(){
    int dimension = 0;
    char caracter;
    char matriz[filas][columnas];
    cout<<"Ingrese la dimension de su matriz: "; cin>>dimension; fflush(stdin);
    //llenamos matriz
    cout<<"\n\nIngrese los caracteres de su matriz: \n"<<endl;
    for(int i=0; i<dimension; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<dimension; j++){
            cout<<"Posicion ["<<i<<"] ["<<j<<"]: "; cin>>matriz[i][j];
        }
    }

    cout<<"\nSu matriz es: \n"<<endl;
    //imprimimos matriz
    for(int i=0; i<dimension; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<dimension;j++){
            cout<<" |"<<matriz[i][j];
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }

    cout<<"\nIngrese el caracter a buscar: "; cin>>caracter;
    cout<<"\nEl caracter '"<<caracter<<"' se encuentra en: ";
    buscarElemento(matriz,dimension,caracter);
    cout<<endl<<endl;

    system("PAUSE");
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: por cierto, esta en C++, pero lo puedes pasar a C sin ningun problema

Comment: Por qué? Cómo resuelve esto el problema del OP? Procura que tu respuesta sea algo más que "usa ésto". Recuerda que esto lo van a usar otros en el futuro. Explícales también.